# How do I handle DateTime values in a vineJS validator?

Tags: adonis.js

In a vineJs validator we have validation function vine.date() however, it doesn't accept any DateTime values (with timezone) as far as I can tell. It will always reject as 'not a valid date'.

Is there some way of getting this to work?